# Gson: Empty JSON conversion error

Tags: java, android, gson

I have the following model:

```java
public class EventSchedule {

    private int id;
    private String date;
    private String time;
    private JSONArray tickets;
    private JSONArray extras;
    private JSONObject venue;

    public EventSchedule(int id, String date, String time, JSONArray tickets,
                         JSONArray extras, JSONObject venue) {

        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.tickets = tickets;
        this.extras = extras;
        this.venue = venue;
    };

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public JSONArray getTickets() {
        return tickets;
    }

    public void setTickets(JSONArray tickets) {
        this.tickets = tickets;
    }

    public JSONArray getExtras() {
        return extras;
    }

    public void setExtras(JSONArray extras) {
        this.extras = extras;
    }

    public JSONObject getVenue() {
        return venue;
    }

    public void setVenue(JSONObject venue) {
        this.venue = venue;
    }
}
```

And I have a JSON array I would like to convert to an `ArrayList` of the model above using the following code:

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<EventSchedule>>(){}.getType();
List<EventSchedule> schedules = gson.fromJson(mEvent.getSchedules().toString(), type);
```

However when I try to run this my activity crashes. This leads me to my first error:

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

So I figured it was impossible to convert a model with a `JSONArray` so I added `transient` to exclude all the `JSONArray` columns and this time it run and didn't crash.

Now for my second problem, whenever I tried getting the `JSONObject` venue it always turned up empty. I do not know why.

So my question now is how do I solve my issue with `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` so that I am able to convert to an `ArrayList`.

Comment: You have mixed things up. Gson does not work with `JSON***` unless custom type adapters added (you might want to use `com.google.gson.Json***`). Your `EventSchedule` is a mix-up of primitives and JSON tree objects -- you should replace the JSON trees with mappings like `EventSchedule`, and not even use `Json***`. Also, `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY` is a too generic error and can occur because of thousand reasons: posting a _minimum_ JSON document might help more. Also, I suspect `tickets` is the root cause of the error (`[...]` in JSON but expected-as-object for `JSONArray`).

Comment: Thank you but I'm confused, what exactly are you saying I should do? What mappings are you saying I should replace my JSON*** with?

Comment: Throw away `JSON***` types and replace the `JSON***` fields with classes like `EventSchedule`. `JSONArray` should be replaced with a collection like `List<...>` or an array.

Comment: This is a local best-seller but it works badly with polymorphic mappings: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ -- just make some experiments and see what the tool generates for your JSON documents.

Answer (score 0):

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

The reason you are getting this error is because you have declare object in your class.

```
 private JSONArray tickets; //Object ref. of JSONArray
 private JSONArray extras;  //Object ref. of JSONArray
```

However your response consisting List of objects so during conversion it find object instead of List

Solution :

Make a class which is will represent your JSONObject in your JSONArray and use it instead in List tickets;